# apt-get update updates every time

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, software-updates

I just got Linux Mint 17.02 Cinnamon on my desktop, and the first time I ran `sudo apt-get update` it asked me something about interfering with files, but I told it to skip over some for whatever reason. Now, when I run `update`, it scans through a ton of files, never saying, "No files updated" or anything like that. Here's a screenshot of what will run 10 times out of 10. Here's the output:

```
matthias@matthias ~ $ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela InRelease                               
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela InRelease                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease                   
Hit http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela Release.gpg                             
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela Release.gpg                          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease                   
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela Release                                 
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela Release                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release.gpg                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/main amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela/main amd64 Packages                     
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release.gpg                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                         
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/upstream amd64 Packages              
Hit http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela/main i386 Packages                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/import amd64 Packages                
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/upstream i386 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/import i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela/main Translation-en_US                  
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela/main Translation-en                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse arm64 Packages   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/import Translation-en_US             
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/import Translation-en       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en   
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/main Translation-en_US               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en           
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/main Translation-en                  
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse Translation-en   
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/upstream Translation-en_US           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en               
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela/upstream Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
```

Is there a way to clear settings or something? I'm not totally sure why it does that so I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks

EDIT: A comment asked for the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources/apt.conf. I do not have the latter, but here is the first one:

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.2 _Rafaela_ - Release amd64 20150721]/ .Trash-1000/files/dists.2/xenial/main/binary-i386/

#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.2 _Rafaela_ - Release amd64 20150721]/ .Trash-1000/files/dists.2/xenial/restricted/binary-amd64/
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.2 _Rafaela_ - Release amd64 20150721]/ .Trash-1000/files/dists.2/xenial/restricted/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.2 _Rafaela_ - Release amd64 20150721]/ trusty contrib main non-free
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.2 _Rafaela_ - Release amd64 20150721]/.Trash-1000/files/ dists.2/xenial/main/binary-amd64/
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.2 _Rafaela_ - Release amd64 20150721]/.Trash-1000/files/ xenial main restricted
```

Comment: Text is text, you can paste it in to the question. Then blind people etc can read it.

Comment: Sure. It's a lot, but I'll paste it. I'm gonna be a little embarrassed if a blind person helps me, not gonna lie

Comment: Read Line 5 “E: Unable to locate package update”, then line 1.

Comment: Hope you re-ran that, and pasted in the new stuff. Not just edit to what you think it should say (I get a lot of my time wasted that way).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52030/discussion-between-richard-and-mana624).

Comment: What's there is what happens every time. Just ran it again

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. Hopefully an expert will be able to help.

Comment: I hope that `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` contains some files, that you can list. If not we may have found a problem (no repositories listed). `#` means ignore this line, it is used for comments, and to disable code.

Comment: It does. It has some PHP, Java, Python, and MongoDB files, among others

Comment: It's because of those files in `sources.list.d` that you have a so long list of repositories to update. See if they are all necessary.

Comment: you should not have programs in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, just a list of repositories. e.g. `deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free` (this one is in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`). It looks like your `sources.list`s may be broken.

Comment: Is there some way to fix it?